# How to enable autoscaling/v2beta2 api-versions in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, memory, minikube, autoscaling, hpa

I don't find autoscaling/v2beta2 or beta1 when I run the command $kubectl api-versions. But I need it for memory autoscaling. What to do ?

To enable autoscaling/v2beta2

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using latest Minikube with Kubernetes 1.26 where `autoscaling/v2beta2` API is no longer served:

> The autoscaling/v2beta2 API version of HorizontalPodAutoscaler is no
> longer served as of v1.26.

Read more: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#horizontalpodautoscaler-v126

So the solution might be either changing API version to `autoscaling/v2` in your manifests or use older version of Minikube/Kubernetes.

Comment: Which version of minikube/kuberentes should I use?

Comment: You can try Minikube v1.27.0 which comes with Kubernetes v1.25 by default